# sending messages to Class - get rid of "multiple methods named [...]" warning

Tags: objective-c

I am passing a Class type as a parameter to a method, and the LLVM compiler in XCode 4.5.2 generates a warning, "multiple methods named 'foo' found", which is understandable, but undesired in this case. How do I get rid of this warning, either by disabling this type of warning, or by making changes to my code?

```
- (void) fooWithClass: (Class) theClass
{
    [theClass aClassMethodOfThatClass];
}
```

more specifically, the parameter is a subclass of a certain base class, and i am sending a message which is declared in that base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the warning, you can check the [clang manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics). Like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
    [theClass aClassMethodOfThatClass];
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: works for an OS X target, but doesn't do anything for iOS. Compiler is set to LLVM 4.1 for both. any idea? thanks!

Comment: I am actually targeting iOS when I tried that piece of code and it removed the warning. I am using `LLVM 4.1` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Deactivating `-Wall` did not work for me, in case anybody is still interested: 
After digging around in the LLVM manual, I found that the exact warning you need to ignore using Peres's method (as of Xcode 7) is:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-selector-match"
// code
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```